# TFS Git - pull requests 'Merge failed'

Tags: git, github, tfs, merge, pull-request

Hi I have this problem with TFS and git pull requests.

We have two main branches:
-master
-develop

So I create new branch async_data_loading from *develop* and do some changes in it. Next I commit and push my changes to remote async_data_loading and then I create new pull request to merge my changes into remote develop and I get this:

[image: TFS Merge fail]

But when I try to find any merge conflicts from console there is none to fix...I can even merge my changes to my local develop without any problems. As you can see below my local branch and develop are on the same 'branch' so there are no conflicts to solve, just my branch is ahead of few commits.

[image: Branches graph]

Anyone had this problem and solved it? I've spent couple of hours searching for the solution but found nothing.

The funny thing is that if I create a test branch from *master* and then follow steps as with develop there are no problems with merging my test branch to master on TFS.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: It's the online TFS at visualstudio.com that we're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the problem is fixed now. We found out that some files from one of the folders were copied and their names were the full path to these files on one of the developers system, something like this:

{PC_name}/Users/{user_name}/{full_path_to_local_file}.cs

When we removed these files TFS suddenly were able to complete merge on server without complaining.

The thing that annoys me is the lack of any information why merge on server failed. This is surely something that MS should fix in a future...

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing a similar problem. In our case, angle brackets (`< >`) in the TFS user's email were making LibGit2Sharp throw an exception under the hood, which was not displayed in the error message in TFS (same visual result as OP described). I also posted an answer here with the stack trace:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39841140/2496266

Answer (score 0):

Just test in TFS 2015.2 + VS 2015.2, can't reproduce this issue.
A conflict often occurs when you merge two branches in which the same file is changed. Make sure you have fetch the latest for *develop* branch before branch it.

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio - working on Mac. We have TFS 2015.

There are no conflicts between branches - I can merge my branch to local develop easily from terminal and then push changes to remote develop without git complaining about merge failing...

Comment: If you delete the branch async_data_loading and create a new one, are you able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yep. I've tried almost everything. TFS can't handle merging any branch that has been created from develop. Seems like we have some issue with develop (maybe history??) but the weird thing is that git itself is able do make merge without any complains...

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this issue on my side. Could you try to create a new git repo to have a test?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue more recently and had a heck of time just finding it.  eventvwr is super-noisy and didn't have any good information for us.

What I did to find the issue was took a version of a code base and put into a diff't repo and set it up as our mainline (develop, whatever).  Then took our full mainline and set it up a feature branch.  I then went into detached mode in our full mainline / feature branch, and started creating different branches (binary search basically).  I created Pull Requests for all those scenarios, if it reproduced the "merge failed" issue I knew I went to far.  If I got a clean merge, I knew I needed to go farther.

Eventually we found a file with a '\' in the name of it.
Removing this file I was able to clear everything up.  I suspect this is because most of the PR/Merging functionality occurs on a Windows platform.

MS if you're listening update eventvwr with less-noisy and more material information.

Comment: Interesting - this wouldn't be limited to Windows, the merge is entirely done in-memory and so path separators shouldn't matter.  I'll try to reproduce this myself.  And thanks for the feedback.  Yes, we are listening.

Comment: Hmm.  What version of TFS are you using?  I can't repro this on VSTS.  Amusingly, there is a _different_ problem, but I can merge a pull request with a filename with a `\` in it.

Comment: Sorry I missed this, I'll followup with my team asap for you.