# TFS Git Pull Request - Merge failed (Why?)

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request

We are using TFS Git to create and merge pull requests. This is working fine for existing users, but when we add new users in AD (copying the exact same rights as existing users), the pull requests from the new users get an error (merge failed).

Access to TFS is presumably granted by adding the user to the project team - no users seem to have any additional access rights that we can find.

We have tried with multiple new users with different names (everything else is the same as existing users), but we are not really getting any closer to understanding why this occurs.

We have also verified that pull requests created on the exact same code, with existing users, do not have this problem.

What can we do to investigate why the merge is failing?

Comment: Is there any sort of log statement available?  Broadly speaking, a pull request can fail for so many reasons.

Comment: Can't find any relevant log statements from TFS in the Event Viewer. Are there other logs I could look at?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Have you tried on the latest edition of TFS 2015? As this workflow has been improved in TFS 2015.

Comment: We are using TFS 2015 Version 14.0.23128.0. We will try to update it - maybe it helps

Comment: Can you share the screenshot for the pull request and merge failed error message?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kmV391Y.png

Comment: The error in your screenshot usually occurs when there is conflict between the two branches that the sever cannot auto resolve. Can you try following with the new AD user: 1. Create a new branch from master. 2. Make some changes in the new branch and commit and push the changes. 3. Create a pull request and make sure there is no change pushed to master after you create the new branch. 4. Check if the pull request can be completed successfully.

Comment: This works, thanks! But why is TFS unable to merge even if there is not a merge conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge the branches in Visual Studio to see whether you'll get conflict or detailed error message. If there is conflicts, use the merge tool to resolve the conflicts, then commit and push the merge.

Comment: As I mentioned we are able to merge the exact same code with a different user. Also, the problematic users are able to merge the branches manually without any problems, so something is happening in TFS here.

Comment: As I'm not able to add a new account to AD to test your scenario, please let us know whether upgrade TFS will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Applications and Services Logs => Microsoft-Team Foundation Server => Debug` in eventvwr.exe for the following:

> LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Failed to parse signature - Neither `name` nor `email` should contain angle brackets chars.
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_signature_new(String name, String email, DateTimeOffset when)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_commit_create(RepositorySafeHandle repo, String referenceName, Signature author, Signature committer, String message, Tree tree, GitOid[] parentIds)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.ObjectDatabase.CreateCommit(Signature author, Signature committer, String message, Tree tree, IEnumerable`1 parents, Boolean prettifyMessage, Nullable`1 commentChar)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.ObjectDatabase.CreateCommit(Signature author, Signature committer, String message, Tree tree, IEnumerable`1 parents, Boolean prettifyMessage)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.Native.LibGit2NativeLibrary.TryMerge(MergeParameters mergeParameters, CustomerIntelligenceData ciData)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.ITfsGitRepositoryExtensions.CreateNativeMerge(ITfsGitRepository repository, IVssRequestContext requestContext, TfsGitPullRequest pullRequest, String targetRefName, Sha1Id targetBranchTipCommit, Sha1Id sourceCommit, CustomerIntelligenceData ciData, GitPullRequestCompletionOptions completionOptions, Nullable`1& mergeCommitId, List`1& includedCommits)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.TeamFoundationGitPullRequestService.CreateUpToDateMerge(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ITfsGitRepository repository, TfsGitPullRequest pullRequest, TfsGitRef& targetRef, Boolean forCompletion, CustomerIntelligenceData ciData)

The issue in our case was that the angle brackets (`< >`) needed to be removed from the offending users' emails.

Note: There is an alternative solution involving TFS-hosted Git file paths pointing to URIs on devs' laptops [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719902/2496266).